# For Each loop on an array of List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))

Tags: vb.net, foreach, keyvaluepair

I'm having problems doing a For Each loop on a "List(Of KeyValuePair(Of" collection.

I'm passing a ParamArray to a Function

```
ParamArray args() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
```

I'm then trying to do a For Each on the Collection

```
For Each arg As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In args
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)'

I just can't figure out how to do this, and I can't find any examples of how to do this.

My only thought right now is to do

```
For Each arg As Object In args
```

Then converting the object to a KeyValuePair, but there must be a neater way of doing this...

Comment: Why not just use a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`?

Comment: As was pointed out args is declared as an array.  If that isn't your intention, removing the `()`'s should fix it.

Comment: @tinstaafl : `args` is passed as a ParamArray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`args` is an array. That means that you have an array of `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))`.

To access each item in a for each you will need to do this (untested):

```
For Each arg As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)) In args
    For Each kvp as KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In arg
    ' Do Stuff
    Next
Next
```

As per my comment above: you'd probably be better off using a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` and some Linq statements.

Edit: Also, depending on what you're trying to do with each item, modifying the item in any way will result in an exception because you can't modify a collection you're iterating over.

Comment: Thanks for that, this option worked fine.

This ParamArray is for a flexible number of Parameters. The original code (VB6) used Optional and isMissing, which I can't do in VB.NET, this was my solution.

Comment: Glad my solution worked. Would you mind marking the question as answered for future reference?

Comment: Click the checkmark beside my answer. It will turn green which will mark the question as answered.

Comment: OK, that wasn't obvious. I was looking at the top for something relating to the original question...

Answer (score 1):

This declares an array of lists:

```
ParamArray args() As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
```

You probably meant an array of KVP (option #1):

```
ParamArray args As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)
```

Or (option #2):

```
args() As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)
```

Or (option #3):

```
args As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
```